# Can't mount block device to directory

Tags: centos, mount, block-device

Checked for existing devices

```
sdb             8:16   0   5.5T  0 disk /mnt/grid/0
sdc             8:32   0   5.5T  0 disk /mnt/grid/1
sdd             8:48   0   5.5T  0 disk /mnt/grid/2
sde             8:64   0   5.5T  0 disk /mnt/grid/3
sdf             8:80   0   5.5T  0 disk /mnt/grid/4
sdg             8:96   0   5.5T  0 disk /mnt/grid/5
sdh             8:112  0   5.5T  0 disk /mnt/grid/6
sdi             8:128  0   5.5T  0 disk /mnt/grid/7
sdj             8:144  0   5.5T  0 disk /mnt/grid/8
sdk             8:160  0   5.5T  0 disk /mnt/grid/9
sdl             8:176  0   5.5T  0 disk /mnt/grid/10
sdm             8:192  0   5.5T  0 disk
sdn             8:208  0   5.5T  0 disk /mnt/grid/12
sdo             8:224  0   5.5T  0 disk /mnt/grid/13
sdp             8:240  0   5.5T  0 disk /mnt/grid/14
```

Shown the unmounted path in sdm

So, I've tried to mount /dev/sdm to /mnt/grid/11 but once entered the command

```
mount /dev/sdm /mnt/grid/11
```

returned `mount: /dev/sdm is not a valid block device`

also checked for `fdisk /dev/sdm`

returned `fdisk: cannot open /dev/sdm: No such device or address`

But actually the device sdm still there because I can access to the directory

```
ll /dev/sdm
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 192 Mar  6 07:02 /dev/sdm
```

The question is why it said /dev/sdm is not a valid block device despite the system seems recognise with the device.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any idea what happened, like, did you eject the drive or something ? can you check `dmesg`, the device  probably caused errors.

Comment: Try rescanning the SCSI bus, then check if the device is still listed.

Comment: Any hints about what kind of block device (USB stick?) this is supposed to be would help. Also try `lsscsi`. Also look in `dmesg` for errors during device removal. Note that in general you only can mount a file system, which usually means a specific partition on a block device, but this step comes after finding out why `/dev/sdm` is gone.

Comment: for an update
Now the support team are checking for the device, seems like it deads.
Thanks for all the comments

Comment: @dirkt A 5.5TB USB stick. Did I fell in a time warp? :)